# Profile an Apache web server's bandwidth

Tags: apache, profiling, bandwidth

If I use 1TB of bandwidth in a month, I'd like to know what it's made up of.

eg, is 80% of it images, 10% CSS, 5% JavaScript and 5% misc files?

I've asked out server company (Rackspace) a few times, and it's simply not a service they offer, nor could they point me to a specific 3rd party app that would provide such information.

Can anyone suggest a method/app which would achieve this? The data would enable actionable insight to reducing bandwidth usage for a website.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

All this information is already captured in your web servers access_log file.

Google for "Apache access log analyzer" and you will find a bunch of tools using which you can analyze various things

[Here is one such tool](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/WebalizerLogfileAnalysis)

Comment: Thanks, in my limited experience (I'm not a sys admin so it really is limited), these tools tend to give you a high level figure for bandwidth. ie, you used 100MB on Thursday, and 150M on Friday.

I'm after a high level breakdown of what that 100M is made up of.

I'll have a dig around though, thanks :)